# consulta en tabla en BD oracle con clausulas internas

Tags: oracle, plsql

[image: EJEMPLO DE DATOS]

HOLA,
 quiero hacer una consulta en ORACLE que me traiga todos los puntajes que sean inferiores a 3.0(AMARILLO) pero no de los que tengan el mismo DERA_FKREGISTROACTIVIDAD y en alguna tenga un puntaje mayor a 3.0, los azules tienen un puntaje menor a 3 pero existe otro DERA_FKREGISTROACTIVIDAD que tiene un puntaje mucho mayor a 3.0

es decir traer los registros en los cuales no allan pasado y los que si no consultarlos

DE ANTEMANO MUCHAS GRACIAS.

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera ademas de agregar el código de la consulta que has intentado. Saludos.

Comment: LO RESOLVÍ DE LA SIGUIENTE FORMA

SELECT COUNT(*), MAX(DERA_PUNTAJE), DERA_FKREGISTROACTIVIDAD FROM CAPACITACIONES.DETALLEREGISTROACTIVIDAD GROUP BY  DERA_FKREGISTROACTIVIDAD

SOLO ES CUESTIÓN DE IMAGINACIÓN

Comment: Duban, si ya lo resolviste, en StackOverflow puedes publicar una respuesta a tu propia pregunta. De esta manera, otros usuarios que lleguen a ella vía la búsqueda, por tener un problema similar, podrán ver claramente de qué manera se resuelve.

Answer (score 0):

LO RESOLVÍ DE LA SIGUIENTE FORMA

```
SELECT COUNT(*), MAX(DERA_PUNTAJE), DERA_FKREGISTROACTIVIDAD FROM CAPACITACIONES.DETALLEREGISTROACTIVIDAD GROUP BY DERA_FKREGISTROACTIVIDAD SOLO ES CUESTIÓN DE IMAGINACIÓN
```